# Analyzing a Dirichlet series with log-oscillating terms via Fourier methods

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I am investigating the series $S(z)$ defined as follows:

$$
S(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-a}\cos(b\ln(n)),
$$

where $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$, with $0 < a < 1$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to understand the conditions under which $S(z)$ converges to a value, where:

- $S(z) < -1$
- $-1 \leq S(z) < 0$
- $0 \leq S(z) < 1$
- $S(z) > 1$

I'm wondering if some kind of Fourier analysis would help here. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in that area

Any pointers to any relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your series diverges for any $a\leq 1$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$, while it is known to converge for any $a>1$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$. See my post below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your series diverges for any $a<1$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$. This is clear for $b=0$, so we can assume $b>0$ (in case of $b<0$, we replace $b$ by $-b$). We shall show that the series does not satisfy [Cauchy's test of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test). More precisely, we shall show that for any $N_0>0$ there exist numbers $N_2>N_1>N_0$ such that
$$\sum_{N_1<n<N_2}n^{-a}\cos(b\ln(n))>1.$$
For given $N_0>0$, we can pick a positive integer $k$ such that the numbers
$$N_1:=e^{(2k\pi-\pi/3)/b}\qquad\text{and}\qquad N_2:=e^{(2k\pi+\pi/3)/b}$$
exceed $N_0$. Then, for any $N_1<n<N_2$ we have
$$2k\pi-\pi/3<b\ln(n)<2k\pi+\pi/3,$$
hence also
$$\cos(b\ln(n))>1/2.$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{N_1<n<N_2}n^{-a}\cos(b\ln(n))\gg\sum_{N_1<n<N_2}n^{-a}\gg e^{(1-a)2k\pi/b}.$$
The right-hand side tends to infinity as $k\to\infty$. In particular, for $k$ sufficiently large, the left-hand side exceeds $1$, and we are done.

**Remark.** A similar argument shows that the series also diverges for $a=1$ and any $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @swami In analytic number theory, the symbol $\gg$ means "bigger than an absolute constant times". The constant can be tiny, e.g. $10^{-100}$. In the last line, the left-hand side is bigger than $(1/2)\sum_{N_1<n<N_2}n^{-a}$ because $\cos(b\ln(n))>1/2$ holds for all $N_1<n<N_2$. And $\sum_{N_1<n<N_2}n^{-a}$ is bigger than an absolute constant times $e^{(1-a)2k\pi/b}$, which in turn is very large for $k$ very large. I hope it is clear now.